# Web Scraping value from <a class="name" href="value" /a>

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I need to scrap the value of [*href*] tag shown on image below:

[image]

Using the code below how can I get the value (449002682) or all the value in the href= tag?

```
Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim htmlEle1 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim htmlEle2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Dim URL As String
Dim elemValue As String

URL = "https://www.informadb.pt/pt/pesquisa/?search=500004064"


    XMLPage.Open "GET", URL, False
    XMLPage.send
    
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText
    
        
    For Each htmlEle1 In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
        Debug.Print htmlEle1.className
        
       If htmlEle1.className = "c-header-lang__link" Then
          
          'Code to check if exist, and get the 'href'-> "#?Duns=449002682"
          'or just the numeric value.
          
       End If
    Next htmlEle1
```

Thank you.

Comment: When I manually navigate to the link you used in your above script, it always leads to a redirected url ending in `Duns=453060832`. However, when I inspect elements of that page, I can see this `#?Duns=453060832`  connected to the class `c-header-lang__link`. Either way, your aforementioned href `#?Duns=449002682` is not present in there.

Comment: Hi @SIM I'm sorry. When I manually navigate to the link in google chrome and do the Inspect, I coud reach to `<a class="c-header-lang__link" href="#?Duns=453060832">
                                    
                                </a>`

Can you help to achive the 453060832, please?

Comment: If I can find any way to catch the redirected url and reuse the same to fetch desired portion from that site, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Most appreciate.@SIM